# Java: object.hashCode() and Objects.hashCode(object)

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

A simple, short question: does `object.hashCode()` and `Objects.hashCode(object)` equal? What is the difference? Do they count the same hash from the objects?

Comment: Search before asking please

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in implementation of it

```
public static int hashCode(Object o) {
    return o != null ? o.hashCode() : 0;
}
```

yes. It prevents from NPE if object o is null.

Answer (score 3):

`Objects.hashCode(object)` will return zero if `object` is `null`.

Whereas a `NullPointerException` would be thrown for `object.hashCode()` in that case.

For a non-`null` reference, the functions are equivalent.